# I did "sudo reboot" on my server and its going web page not found

Tags: server

i did above command my ftp works fine but website give me error like

This webpage is not available

Comment: have you verified apache2 is running?

Comment: i have apt dir and i use etc/init.d/apt restart but still same error

Comment: you can ask about cent and get the best answers at unix stackexchange instead: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible cases:

your apache server is off

to run it

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Or you misstype the name of your website page

Comment: i have apt dir and i use etc/init.d/apt restart but still same error

Comment: what is the output of `sudo service apache2 start`

Comment: sudo : service :  command not found

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: don't know how to check any command , its i think linux

Comment: Linux cyz.com 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: output of `lsb_release -d`?

Comment: Description:    CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

Comment: rubn this command `/sbin/service apache2 start`

Comment: yep work i had run /sbin/service httpd restart for restart thanks lot